# php if (not this or not this) {do some thing}

Tags: php, if-statement

I try this a lot of time but it not working.
I want to do like first one chicking but second one not working. Please Help Me

This code is working.

```
<?php
    $a = 2;

    if ( $a == 2 || $a == 3 ) {
        echo "OK";
    }else {
        echo "Error !!!!!!!";
    }
?>
```

but this one not working its all time true.

```
<?php
    $a = 2;

    if ( $a !== 2 || $a !== 3 ) {
        echo "Error";
    }
?>
```

Please Help Me

Comment: Try != instead of !==

Comment: The second one is always true because one of those statements is always true since $a can't be 2 and 3.

Comment: @ChrisG That won't make a difference

Comment: How I do work like first one only if statement. Demo Please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Break it down:

```
if ( $a !== 2 || $a !== 3 ) {
    echo "Error";
}
```

Note two things:

- If `$a==2` then `$a!==3`.
- If `$a==3` then `$a!==2`.

This means that one of those conditions will ALWAYS be true, so the `if` statement will ALWAYS execute, as `||` is an OR statement.

---

If you want to execute if `$a` is not 2 OR 3, then you should write:

```
if ( $a !== 2 && $a !== 3 ) {
```

OR:

```
if ( ! ( $a == 2 || $a == 3) ) {
```

That way, the code will only execute when `$a` is neither `2` nor `3`.

---

This is explored in the Wikipedia article on [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) (thanks @Marc), which states:

> The rules allow the expression of conjunctions and disjunctions purely in terms of each other via negation.
>
> The rules can be expressed in English as:
>
> The negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations.
> The negation of a disjunction is the conjunction of the negations.
>
> or informally as:
>
> **"not (A and B)"** is the same as **"(not A) or (not B)"**
> also,
> **"not (A or B)"** is the same as **"(not A) and (not B)"**.

Comment: Thanks @Marc, added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Logics a bit different when asking for something not being equal to:

```
if(!(a==2 || a==3)){}
```

What you said initially will translate into "if not a is 2 or not a is 3 then...", whereas what you want is "if a not is 2 or 3 then ..."